# JQuery Toggle Between multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle between divs so that when an  tag is clicked a div will show. 
When another a tag is clicked, the div will replace the div shown.

This is what I did.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" rel="#slidingDiv">a</a><br>
<a href="#" rel="#slidingDiv_2">b</a><br>
<a href="#" rel="#slidingDiv_3">c</a><br>
<a href="#" rel="#slidingDiv_4">d</a><br>

<div id="slidingDiv">a</div>
<div id="slidingDiv_2">a</div>
<div id="slidingDiv_3">a</div>
<div id="slidingDiv_4">a</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
function ($) {
$.fn.showHide = function (options) {

    //default vars for the plugin
    var defaults = {
        speed: 1000,
        easing: '',
        changeText: 0,
        showText: 'Show',
        hideText: 'Hide'

    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    $(this).click(function () { 

                var toggleDiv;

                var $divA = $('#slidingDiv'),
                    $divB = $('#slidingDiv_2'),
                        $divC = $('#slidingDiv_3'),
                        $divD = $('#slidingDiv_4'),
                        $divE = $('#slidingDiv_5'),
                        $divF = $('#slidingDiv_6'),
                        $divG = $('#slidingDiv_7'),
                        $divH = $('#slidingDiv_8'),
                        $divI = $('#slidingDiv_9');

                if( $divA.is( ':visible' ) ){
                        $divA.hide();
            }
                if( $divB.is( ':visible' ) ){
                        $divB.hide();
            }
                if( $divC.is( ':visible' ) ){
                        $divC.hide();
            }
                if( $divD.is( ':visible' ) ){
                        $divD.hide();
            }
                if( $divE.is( ':visible' ) ){
                        $divE.hide();
            }
                if( $divF.is( ':visible' ) ){
                        $divF.hide();
            }
                if( $divG.is( ':visible' ) ){
                        $divG.hide();
            }
                if( $divH.is( ':visible' ) ){
                        $divH.hide();
            }
                if( $divI.is( ':visible' ) ){
                        $divI.hide();
            }

                // this reads the rel attribute of the button to determine which div id to toggle
                toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel'); 


      $('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);   

                // this var stores which button you've clicked
      var toggleClick = $(this);

          var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel');

              // here we toggle show/hide the correct div at the right speed and using which easing effect
          $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function() {
            // this only fires once the animation is completed
                // if(options.changeText==0){
              //$(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
               //}

          });

      return false;

    });

};
})(jQuery);
```

This currently works, but I know that this can be done better instead of using the if statement.

Thanks

Comment: You could also get rid of all those numbered ID's and use the element's index + a common class. This question would be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Use classes! Save you tons of time! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951556/show-hide-divs-with-same-class-jquery

Comment: That's my point... I want to get rid of if statements. I know there is a best way in doing this.. I was searching through jsfiddle and found this: http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/62NPt/4/

But for me it does not work

Answer (score 4):

Here we go: http://jsfiddle.net/fqK36/5/

Your whole function becomes:

```
$.fn.showHide = function (options) {

    //default vars for the plugin
    var defaults = {
        speed: 1000,
        easing: '',
        changeText: 0,
        showText: 'Show',
        hideText: 'Hide',
        slideDiv: '.slide-div'
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            $(options.slideDiv).hide();
            // this var stores which button you've clicked
            var toggleClick = $(this),
                toggleDiv = $(this).data('slide-id');
            // here we toggle show/hide the correct div at the right speed and using which easing effect
            $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function () {
                // this only fires once the animation is completed
                // if(options.changeText==0){
                //$(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
                //}

            });


        });

    });

};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
$('a').showHide({'slideDiv' : '.slide-div'});
```

The `slideDiv` option can be a custom selector you're using can the divs you wish to slide.

All slides are assigned a class which means you can hide them all at once. Then you can show the targeted `div` by getting the clicked link's `data-slide-id` attribute.

Comment: Didn't work. I must have done something wrong. They are coming underneath each other

Comment: Make sure you look at the jsfiddle link and update your html so it looks like mine.

Comment: @Joe You should probably make sure the plugin handles being applied to multiple sets of elements. As it is, it's a bit useless as a plugin, because it can only be used once. You could put a `data-slide-group` attribute on the divs and pass that group name as a plugin option.

Comment: @plalx - excellent point! I just came across my answer and updated it. Now you can define a custom selector to use for the sliding divs and it also supports chaining.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I do this by creating a `hidden` class. When you go to switch to a new div, you can do something like this:

```
$(this).click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hidden') 

    $('div:not(#' + $(this).attr('id') + ')').addClass('hidden')
});
```

This uses the `not` selector to find everything but your current item. Sans animation, this is the simple way to do it. You can also grab whatever is not hidden by using `$('div:not(.hidden)')` and then run your toggle on everything in that selector.

```
$(this).click(function(){

    if($(this).hasClass('hidden'){
        $(this).show()

        $(this).removeClass('hidden')
    }

    $('div:not(#' + $(this).attr('id') + ') :not(.hidden.)')
        .hide().addClass('hidden')
});
```

Might help clean things up a bit.